# Toast width doesnt match its content

Tags: android, toast

My code:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "انتهای کتاب", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Result (on eclipse emulator, android2.2):

[image]

Comment: have you tried on device???

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, give the same result (android 2.3)

Comment: i have tested it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "انتهای کتاب", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```